# powershell cannot ping a web address

Tags: powershell, ping

I run powershell as Admin in Windows 10 64Bit. When I ping `www.powershellgallery.com` I get error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ping www.powershellgallery.com

Pinging psg-prod-eastus.cloudapp.net [40.87.85.101] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 40.87.85.101:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
```

But when I ping other web addresses, google.com for example, everything is fine.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ping www.google.com

Pinging www.google.com [216.58.213.68] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.213.68: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 216.58.213.68: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=56
Reply from 216.58.213.68: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=56
Reply from 216.58.213.68: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 216.58.213.68:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 13ms, Maximum = 15ms, Average = 13ms
```

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Is your network being banned, for example like what it is in China?

Comment: I am in UK. It seems that my machine cannot ping any Azure website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really is not a powershell issue. Matter of fact this isnt a issue at all. Ping is using ICMP. Its basically an echo message. Companies can block and not allow ICMP.

So just because there is no ping doesnt mean that something is not working.

Comment: When I try to install a package from PSGallery I get an error. Also Get-PSRepository does not work. But two other colleagues can access PSGallery normally. It has something to do with my laptop, not in general with the company I work.

Comment: You Question wasnt about loading a package. It was why couldnt you ping.

Comment: @user3417479 You need to close this question as its not a pinging issue. And ask the correct question of why a package wont load and the code you are using to load a package

Comment: you are right. pinging does not work even on operating laptops. At least we learnt something

Answer (score 6):

Some web-servers are configured to not respond to ping. As ArcSet replied above, the fact that ping fails doesn't mean the website is down.
Fortunately, there's a quick fix for you: Test-NetConnection, which allows you to check for a specific port. The syntax is as follows (in this case, for HTTPS):

`Test-NetConnection powershellgallery.com -Port 443`

Further more, you may add the switch InformationLevel. In this case, the response is much shorter (True or False), which is very convenient if you want to use this in a script.

`Test-NetConnection powershellgallery.com -Port 443 -InformationLevel Quiet`

Cheers.